# Attaching Window Resize event to each element saparately

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been trying to figure out how, can I attach a Windows Resize event separately to each element (these elements are appended dynamically by PHP via ajax invoke).

The problem I also have is that I am utilizing global variables i.e. the variable **id**.

I am trying to figure out how I can attach Window Resize even separately to each element.

EDIT: Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean? Just select something different than `window` then? `$('textarea').resize();`?

Comment: just have a look at `jQuery each`

Comment: @Alex Do you know how to attach events separately to each element? Especially a Window Resize event to keep position.

Comment: Your fiddle and screenshot are useless. No elements with class btnPrimary and popover in them. Don't stick your question to 'how to bind resize to elements' (maybe thats not the sollution). Instead show us what you have and describe clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MIvanIsten This is a fiddle that illustrates a little bit, that it's inline modification of positions (left, right, bottom, and top). The screenshot shows what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: That 'little bit' is a problem. In your fiddle is no js at all, no link with class 'btnPrimary', nothing with class 'popover'. Your fiddle does nothing. There is nothing we can fix on it.

Comment: @MIvanIsten There's nothing to fix so, the problem is, that I want to know how to attach an event e.g. Window Resize and adjust positions for absolute elements.

Comment: There is no `element.on('window resize')` only `element.on('resize')`. You are on wrong way. Thats way I wrote my first comment.

Comment: I am using, $(window).resize to modify the left position inline with css() jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64936/discussion-between-john-smith-and-mivanisten).

Comment: typical xy problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the PHP and the id it assigned to the element, so all three elements have the same ID. That makes sense. So I modified the ID inline and realized the .each() method works.

Comment: The id on elements should be unique (there should not be more than one element with the same id). If you want identify a group of elements, use class.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can attach custom events to any element.

So, add the event "resize" (this event only exist for window element, so here, it's a custom event, you can name it like you want)

```
$("#" + id).on("resize", function(){

    // Do stuff here

});
```

And trigger it from window resize

```
$(window).on("resize", function(){

    $("#" + id).trigger("resize");

});
```

**EDIT :**

If you want that every `"#" + id` has "resize" event, event if appended in document later.

```
$(document).on("resize", "#" + id, function(){

    // Do stuff here

});
```